Upgrading iOS Target Platform to meet minimal Pod version requirements
I have an iOS project that I am building in XCode/Cocoa Pods. When I run the pod install commands I get a lot of warnings for many (if not all) of my pods:

"[!] The platform of the target myapp (iOS 11.0) may not be compatible with <the-name-and-version-of-the-pod-here> which has a minimum requirement of iOS 12.4."

What setting in Xcode or my Podfile can I change to "upgrade" my "target platform" so that it meets the minimal version requirement of all these pods (which across the board are "12.4")?
Under Target > Build Settings/General tabs in Xcode, everything is currently set to 13.0, so I'm not sure why Cocoa Pods is thinking I am targeting version 11 of anything.

You could try updating the minimum supported version of your target. In Xcode,  update Target > Build Settings > Deployment > iOS Deployment Target to 12.4 or preferred version.
Also update the Minimum Deployments in Target > General to 12.4 or preferred version.
(Xcode 15.2)

Yes thanks but both are already set to 13.0, this is what I can't figure out! Where would the 11 be coming from?

do you have a .xcconfig? or search for IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET or search for 11.0 itself in the codebase. Just throwing ideas if you haven't tried already
